No adapter attached; skipping layout, Data is not dsiplaying on Fragment
The Problem i am getting in log cat while trying to display the data. App is not crashing but fragment or Screen getting blank nothing shows on it.
I am Trying to display the All Parks data on the Fragment using Recycleview Adaptor everythinks works fine but Data is not Displaying.



import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.nationalparks.adaptor.ParkRecyclerViewAdoptor;
import com.example.nationalparks.data.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.nationalparks.data.Repository;
import com.example.nationalparks.model.Park;

import java.util.List;

public class ParksFragment extends Fragment {
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private ParkRecyclerViewAdoptor parkRecyclerViewAdoptor;
        private List<Park> parkList;

    public ParksFragment() {
    }


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ParksFragment newInstance() {
        ParksFragment fragment = new ParksFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Repository.getParks(parks ->
                parkRecyclerViewAdoptor= new ParkRecyclerViewAdoptor(parks));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(parkRecyclerViewAdoptor);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parks, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.park_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }
}```


That message means no adapter has been set for your recycler view.  I'm not sure why you have the setup of the recycler view broken into 2 lifecycle functions, but it appears the second isn't being called.

So what shoulld i do beacue my objective is to display all Parks Data when i click on Park Tag

Have you checked that Repository.getParks() returns some content? Have you checked that ParksFragment actually gets instantiated and displayed? Is there any other visible content in its layout or could you add something just to visually confirm it's displayed? Have you added breakpoints to the methods in ParksFragment and debugged the app to see if the methods get called?

Yes Its Returning All the data but only one Item is getting displayed rather than all the item which are added into the list

This does seem a bit "funny" as it creates a new ParkRecyclerViewAdoptor for each Park and then you use the last adapter instance: Repository.getParks(parks -> parkRecyclerViewAdoptor= new ParkRecyclerViewAdoptor(parks));. Also contents of the ParkRecyclerViewAdoptor would be relevant in the question as it's supposedly a custom implementation of RecyclerView.Adapter.
